# How do I write a rsyslog rule to forward conditional on facility and fromhost?

Tags: linux, configuration, rsyslog

This `rsyslog` rule forwards `syslog` and `auth` facilities to another host:

```
syslog,auth.*                                  @another-host
```

The following (taken from [here](http://rsyslog-users.1305293.n2.nabble.com/Setting-up-redundant-central-logservers-td7580929.html)) forwards syslogs conditional on fromhost:

```
:fromhost-ip, !isequal, 192.178.23.10 @192.178.23.10:514
```

**Question**: How can I combine the two? I'd like a rsyslog rule to the effect of "forward all `syslog` and `auth` syslogs to `another-host` if fromhost is not equal to otherlogserver's IP`"

I tried the following that did not seem to work:

```
:fromhost-ip, !isequal, 192.178.23.10 syslog,auth.* @another-host
```

In general, I'm not sure how you're supposed to debug the validity of rsyslog configuration settings; I don't know whether the above is even semi-valid or utter nonsense, but restarting the rsyslog service did not produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is considered proper or elegant by those experienced with `rsyslog` configuration files, but this seemed to work:

```
if $fromhost-ip != '192.178.23.10' and ($syslogfacility-text == 'syslog' or $syslogfacility-text == 'auth') then @another-host
```